# C - how to convert user char input to ASCII

Tags: c, ascii

Basically I need convert user input in "char letter" to ASCII number and that number store in code and not print it. What i mean by that, lets say the user input letter "A". I want to convert it to ascii so 65 and then use that ascii number in math calculations.

Comment: What is the character code of user input? EBCDIC for example?

Comment: The character you input has already been converted to a number. The "character" is just how it looks on the screen, a keyboard, or a printer. Just print it as a number and you'll see what it is.

Comment: If your system uses ASCII this character is already an integer with proper ASCII code.

Comment: I believe you can test that its already a number by doing `printf("%d", your_char);`

Comment: `int charvalue[] = { 'A', 'B', ...}; int asciivalue[] = { 65, 66, ...};` then just find your character in the 1st array and use that index into the 2nd array. BTW: if you're on an ASCII based computer, you realize the contents of the two arrays are 100% absolutely the same and you don't need converting anything whatsoever ('A' == 65 == 'A' in all situations) :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a character input, you actually do receive the ASCII value of the input.
For example,

```
char a;
scanf("%c",&a);
printf("%d",(int)a);
```

try to run this code. It will print the ASCII of the letter you pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your job is just to read every 8bit (1byte) of the input value and you have its code already. Unless you print it to the screen, it is converted to text.